# GET 400 (Bad Request) with jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf, jsonp

I have a `Wcf Service`, I call it from `JavaScript` by `Jquery` (AJAX).

Here is part of the code:

IService1.cs:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService1
 {
   [WebInvoke(Method = "*",
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   [OperationContract]
   User GetUser(string userName, string password);
 }
```

Service1.svc.cs:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public User GetUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Service1.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ProjName.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ProjName.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ProjName.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name=""/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The call to Wcf function from my JS page:

```
function CallService() {

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    error: function (x, e) {
        if (x.status == 0) {
            alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        } else if (x.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested URL not found.');
        } else if (x.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error.');
        } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        } else if (e == 'timeout') {
            alert('Request Time out.');
        } else {
            alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
        }
    }
});

var request = { userName: "aaa", password: "123" };
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(request);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: "http://localhost:xxxx/Service1.svc/GetUser", // Location of the service
    data: jsondata, //Data sent to server
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
    dataType: "jsonp", //Expected data format from server
    async: false,
    processdata: true, //True or False
    crossDomain: true, //True or False
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    }
});

}
```

On `IE` I get the error: `Error. Parsing JSON Request failed.`

On `Chorme` is not coming to the function of the error, but in console I got an error: `GET http://localhost... 400 (Bad Request) .`

I do not understand why it informs an error in `GET` when I pass `POST`, and what the Bad Request.

I would love some help ..

Comment: jsonp works as GET only, I suppose.

Comment: @EnterSB. Even if I turn the `POST` to `GET`, I continue to get this error.

Comment: Web config doesn't have mex endpoints...

Comment: @Pranav. Where i should add it?

Comment: Web config you provided is for website where you are consuming wcf service ?? if it is so, "address" tag can't be empty in endpoint. If config is for WCF service, add mex endpoint in <service> tag like <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>

Comment: @Pranav. Now it works in IE. But in Chrome I get an error: OPTIONS http://localhost... 400 (Bad Request) .

Comment: That's not an issue with browser. Please clear cache/history on chrome then run the application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32827/discussion-between-hodaya-shalom-and-pranav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web config you provided is for website where you are consuming wcf service ??

If it is so, "**address**" tag can't be empty in endpoint.

If config is for WCF service, add mex endpoint in `<service>` tag like

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
```